# iptables how to specify port forwarding for only a few IPs

Tags: linux, iptables

I inherited a complex iptables script acting as our gateway/router. It handles everything well, including NAT and harpin nat. It also does port forwarding. However, the port forwarding can't be specified by source IP. So if the port 25 is forwarded, every IP can connect to that port.

The FORWARD chain policy is `ACCEPT`. I tried to change it to `DROP` and built some rules. It seems that there are too much on specifying rules for every allow scenario.

What I am looking for is to specify things like this:

> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i $WAN_IFACE --dport 25 -s (!(1.1.1.1 and
>   1.1.1.2)) -j DROP

But iptables does not support `and` and `or`.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new chain for all packets going to Port 25 and then do more specific filtering there:

```
iptables -N port25
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i $WAN_IFACE --dport 25 -j port25
iptables -A port25 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A port25 -s 1.1.1.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A port25 -j DROP
```

The creation of user-defined chains is the way to implement `and` and `or` rules.